# Speed up inserting IDs from one large mysql table to another

Tags: php, mysql, database

I can achieve what I want to do it's just terribly slow and I'm pretty sure there is a better way. Here is an abstract:

I have two tables I imported from two text files (via LOAD DATA INFILE). There is no primary and foreign key relationship between these tables yet.

Table 1 - Events: 1.5 millions rows (`person_id` values are empty)

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| event_id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| person_id    | int(11)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| event_details| longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| person_name  | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| mother_name  | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table 2 - People: 140 000 rows

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| person_id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| person_name  | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| mother_name  | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I'm trying to insert the `person_id` from the `people` table into the `events` table.

I've tried a few methods, basically loop through each row of the `events` table find the `person_id` in the `people` table using the `person_name` and `mother_name` in the current row from the `events` table. Then insert the `person_id` into the `events` table.

My current query takes a bout 5 days to update all 1.5 million rows in the `events` table. How can I make this faster?

I'm using laravel and php but any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Why store a `person_id` **and** their name in an adjacent field..? Why not create a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: Can you show us the query(s) you're doing now?

Comment: To avoid finding duplicate `person_name`s it searches for `person_name` and `mother_name`

Comment: And so to be clear .. you lookup the person_name and mother_name in people table and lookup it up in the events table so you can update the people_id (in events table)?

Comment: @fransyozef yes that is basically what I'm doing.

Comment: Try this one : UPDATE events,people SET events.person_id = people.people_id WHERE events.person_id IS NULL AND (people.person_name = events.person_name AND people.mother_name = events.mother_name)